# Mysql query to select all rows with a certain value and 5 other rows without that value

Tags: mysql

I want a mysql query that selects all rows with a specified value on a column and 5 rows without that value.

```
Select * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE is_read=1 
OR (is_read=0 AND found_rows_of_this_value<5)
```

So if we have 100 rows with `is_read=1` we get a result of 105 rows

and if we have 0 rows with `is_read=1` we get a result of 5 rows.

Comment: A simple union all with limits should do see ORDER BY and LIMIT in Unions here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html for an example

Comment: @P.Salmon Thnk you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UNION. UNION combines the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set. The "LIMIT 5" returns only 5 rows. U can change it for get more.

```
Select * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE is_read=1
UNION (
Select * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE is_read=0
LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: Please also describe and share how you answer solves the original question.